# Error with volley library in using POST method in Laravel

Tags: android, laravel, android-volley

I'm creating an app with login/register system and I'm using volley library.
When I'm using WAMP, POST methods are working fine but when I switched to Laravel Homestead it gives me an error.

The error says

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500
```

I've done some searching about this problem but I'm having a hard time understanding their system. I hope somebody could give me some advice based on my program.

Here is a part of my activity that gets the response from my php file
MainScreen.java

```
 Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonresposne = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonresposne.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success) {


                                int user_id = jsonresposne.getInt("uid");
                                Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this,""+user_id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Cart c = new Cart();
                                c.getUserID(user_id);

                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainScreen.this, MainActivity.class);

                                startActivity(intent);
                                pd.dismiss();
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainScreen.this);

                                builder.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>LOGIN FAILED</font>")).setMessage("email and password did not match")
                                        .setCancelable(false)
                                        .setNegativeButton("Ok", null).create().show();
                                pd.dismiss();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                };

                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(password, email, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainScreen.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);

            }
```

This is my LoginRequest.java

```
public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://192.168.1.102:8000/app/login";
private Map<String,String> params;

public LoginRequest(String email, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){

    super(Request.Method.POST,LOGIN_REQUEST_URL,listener,null);

    params =  new HashMap<>();

    params.put("email",email);
    params.put("password",password);


}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

}

and here is my php file with POST methods
login.php

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","homestead","secret","laraveldb");

$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=? AND password=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"ss",$password,$email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement,$id);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){

    $response["success"] = true;
    $response["uid"] = $id;





}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: first of all check you web api working fine or not using chrome extension `Advance Rest client1`or `postman`

Comment: my app is working fine in WAMP. the only problem is using Laravel. I don't understand why chrome extension and web api are here.?

Comment: these are tools to check whether your web api working fine or not. beacuse error is on server side

Comment: ok i wilk try. but most of my research says that it is on the POST method of the Volley library which is a problem if you are using Laravel.

Comment: _Note:_ your approach has nothing to do with _Laravel_. You should implements at least one _Controller_ and the API middleware using something like _Laravel Passport, JWT_, etc. I suggest you _Retrofit_ instead of _Volley_ (_Volley_ requires a lot of boilerplates).

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion sir but It will be hard for me to learn how to use Retrofit. there are a lot of queries already inside my app that requires post method. I'm just using this log in sample because once I get to understand the way on how it will work with volley, I can implement it on other Activites. I've got like 10 Activities that ask for queries with the help of volley. Thank you for your suggestion sir but this is for our thesis project and the deadline is near.

Comment: @ClaudeDubouzet your url `http://192.168.1.102:8000/app/login` not working I am trying to figure out the problem.

Comment: that url is used when I try to connect with laravel. in wamp i'm using 192.168.254.12:8090/app/login.php. Maybe you're right that it is on the server side. The answer will be on "How to allow POST method on laravel". I guess that would fix my problem.

Comment: thank you for helping me @SaurabhBhandari